# Есть такой JS(для анимации скролла), подскажите пожалуйста где нужно поменять классы, что б он работал?

Tags: javascript, html, css, прокрутка

Есть такой JS(для анимации скролла), подскажите пожалуйста куда нужно подставлять свои классы?

```
$(".learn-more").on("click", "a", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).attr('href'),
    top = $(id).offset().top;
  $('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: top
  }, 1000);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно меню задать класс `learn-more`, ссылкам в меню установить значения `href` в виде якорей `#link`, а блокам, к которым предполагается скролл, добавить соответствующие `id`. Вот пример:

```js
$(".learn-more").on("click", "a", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).attr('href');
  var top = $(id).offset().top;
  $('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: top
  }, 1000);
})
```

```css
.blocks {
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="learn-more">
  <a href="#one">Блок 1</a>
  <a href="#two">Блок 2</a>
  <a href="#three">Блок 3</a>
</nav>
<div class="blocks" id="one">БЛОК 1</div>
<div class="blocks" id="two">БЛОК 2</div>
<div class="blocks" id="three">БЛОК 3</div>
```